# Tinymce 4: how to prevent showing the insert or selection toolbars with the inlite theme of an inline editor?

Tags: tinymce, inline

How to prevent this panel from showing up?

When you put a cursor in a blank line, it shows this panel:

[image: Panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two settings are controlled by the `insert_toolbar` and `selection_toolbar` options in your TinyMCE configuration.  If you put this in the configuration:

```
insert_toolbar: '',
selection_toolbar: '',
```

...they will no longer appear.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, insert_toolbar: ''; did the trick. I need the selection toolbar though.